# Unable to load class 'kotlin.coroutines.Continuation'

Tags: kotlin, gradle

This error keeps happening every once in a while in my Kotlin projects. I tried several Kotlin versions (1.3.41, 1.3.60, 1.3.72) but this seems to come up on any version and in various projects. Once it starts happening, I can't build any project.

Full error message:

> Unable to load class 'kotlin.coroutines.Continuation'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>   Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>
> **Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)**
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. 
>    Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>
> **Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)**
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I have tried all the suggestions and none of it helped. When I click
"Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)", it says
[image: project is not a Gradle-bsed project]

Clicking "Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)" restarts Intellij but doesn't help.

Closing Intellij and killing Java processes didn't help either.

Comment: You might have to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While none of the linked suggestions in the error popup worked, running 'clean' gradle task manually did do the trick!

```
./gradlew clean
```

The error still comes up every once in a while but can be reliably fixed by running gradle clean.